# How to stop grid-collection from iteration inside for loop in Liquid Shopify

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, shopify, liquid

I need to stop the grid-collection div to iterate inside for loop.

Here is my sample code in liquid:

```
{% for block in section.blocks %}

    {% if block.settings.download_title %}      
     <div class="title">
      <div class="heading_title">
        <p class="title"><h2>Title</h2></p>
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
        <p class="heading_desc">Description</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if block.settings.image %} 
          <div class="grid-collection-{{ section.settings.grid_number }}">
            <div class="grid-list-view">
                <img style="height: 277px;" src="{{ block.settings.image | img_url: '300x' }}" alt="{{ block.settings.image | escape }}">
            </div>
          </div> 
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

The output of the above code is here:

[image]

**My goal is to insert all `grid-list-view` div inside `grid-collection` div.**

Just like the below output:

[image]

**How to implement this one using Liquid or JavaScript?**

Comment: You need to modify the HTML structure and title need to be inside, the `grid-collection-three`

Comment: Still doesn't fix the problem. I want to iterate the grid-collection-three once the title div is trigger.

Comment: You can't, you need to put the `grid-colleciton-three` outside the `for` and wrap the `title` also inside it.

Comment: Nothing works, I want the title above the grid-list-view so that the output will be title and below are the grid-list-view. How to achieve that kind of approach?

Comment: this is not doable

Comment: are you able to share the block schema for better understanding?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to move `download_title` outside, and loop the `section.blocks` inside the `grid-collection-three` div

something like this:

```
    {% if section.settings.download_title %}      
     <div class="title">
      <div class="heading_title">
        <p class="title"><h2>Title</h2></p>
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
        <p class="heading_desc">Description</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    {% endif %}

    <div class="grid-collection-{{ section.settings.grid_number}}">
      {% for block in section.blocks %}
        {% if block.settings.image %}
        <div class="grid-list-view">
            <img style="height: 277px;" src="{{ block.settings.image | img_url: '300x' }}" alt="{{ block.settings.image | escape }}">
        </div>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </div>

{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "myTitle",
    "blocks" : [
      {
        "type": "slide",
        "name": "Slide",
        "limit": 3,
        "settings": [
          {
            "id": "image",
            "type": "image_picker",
            "label": "Image"
          }
        ]
      }      
    ],
    "settings" :  [
      {
        "id" : "download_title",
        "type" : "text",
        "default" : "text"
      },
      {
        "id" : "grid_number",
        "type" : "text",
        "default" : "three"
      }
    ]

  }
{% endschema %}
```